# Spark executor metrics don't reach prometheus sink

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, prometheus

**Circumstances:**
I have read through these:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/monitoring.html 
https://dzlab.github.io/bigdata/2020/07/03/spark3-monitoring-1/

versions: Spark3.1.2, K8s v19

I am submitting my application via

```
-c spark.ui.prometheus.enabled=true
-c spark.metrics.conf=/spark/conf/metric.properties
```

***metric.properties:***

```
*.sink.prometheusServlet.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet
*.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/prometheus
```

**Result:**
Both of these endpoints have some metrics

```
<driver-ip>:4040/metrics/prometheus        
<driver-ip>:4040/metrics/executors/prometheus
```

the first one - the driver one - has all the metrics
the second one - the executor one - has all the metrics except the ones under the executor namespace
described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/monitoring.html#component-instance--executor
So everything is missing from `bytesRead.count` to `threadpool.startedTasks`
But these metric are indeed reported by the executors, because under /api/v1/applications/app-id/stages/stage-id I can see those too. 
I am struggled with this for hours, moving the configs to --conf flag, splitting up the configs by instances, enabling everything...etc No result.

However if I change the sink from prometheus to **ConsoleSink**:

```
*.sink.console.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.ConsoleSink
*.sink.console.period=10
*.sink.console.unit=seconds
```

Then the metrics appear successfully.

So something is definitely wrong with the Spark-K8s-Prometheus integration.

**Note:**

One interesting stuff is if I split up the config by instances like

```
driver.sink.prometheusServlet.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet
executor.sink.prometheusServlet.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet
driver.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/prometheus1
executor.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/executor/prometheus1
```

(note the trailing '1' at the end)
Then the executor sink path is not taken into account , the driver metrics will be on
`/metrics/prometheus1` but the exectutors will be still on `/metrics/executor/prometheus`.
The class config is indeed working because if I change it to a nonexisting one, then the executor will throw an error as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking to understand why custom user metrics are not sent to the driver, while the regular spark metrics are.

It looks like the PrometheusSink use the class [ExecutorSummary](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/status/api/v1/PrometheusResource.scala), which doesn't allow to add custom metrics.

For the moment, it seems the only working way is to use the JMXExporter (and use the [Java agent to export to Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter)), or just use the ConsoleSink with

```
    *.sink.console.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.ConsoleSink
```